# Finding generalised eigenvector - $(A-\lambda*I)^2$ is all zeros.

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, determinant

So I'm solving some systems of differential equations, and while doing that I have to find the generalised eigenvector. But when I calculate $(A-\lambda I)^2$ all I get is a matrix full of zeros.

This is the matrix A i start with.

$
 \begin{pmatrix}
  3 & 5 \\
  -5 & -7 
 \end{pmatrix}
$

I find $\lambda = -2 $ with algebraic multiplicity 2.

Giving me $(A+2I)$ = 
$
 \begin{pmatrix}
  5 & 5 \\
  -5 & -5 
 \end{pmatrix}
$

and eigenvector 
$
 \begin{pmatrix}
  -1 \\
  1 
 \end{pmatrix}
$

So now, to find the generalised eigenvector, i need to find $\ker(A+2I)^2$

But when finding $(A+2I)^2$ i get : $
 \begin{pmatrix}
  0 & 0 \\
  0 & 0
 \end{pmatrix}
$

What do i do in this situation?

Answer (score 0):

If $(A+2I)^{2}=0$, then $\ker(A+2I)^{2}=\mathbb{R}^{2}$ (if you're working on $\mathbb{R}$), so the only possible Jordan form is $\left[\begin{matrix}-2 & 1 \\ 0 & -2\end{matrix}\right]$.